# Can a generic class inherit from MonoBehaviour?

Tags: unity, c#

Expanding upon a previous tutorial, I am adapting a follow script to support multiple variations of a Bezier spline. Each spline variation uses a custom interface called `IBezierInterface`, and the follow script accesses the method `GetPointOnCurve()` to determine the correct position. In theory, this all seems very simple. However, I appear to be running in to some trouble. While I intend to pursue the general issues a bit more, myself, I realise that I may be shooting myself in the foot with the generic implementation.

While I can find a lot of good examples demonstrating the correct use of generic types, I can not find anything that gives an example of a generic class that inherits from another class. For example, [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) includes examples of inheritance as a *restriction* on the actual type, and an example of inheriting *from* a generic class; but there are no examples of a generic class that inherits from a standard class. [Unity documentation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/generics) has even less examples, but none pertaining to my query. I am not getting errors; *but that is no guarantee against error*. I can not conceive a good prototype model to test my theory, either, given the fact that I am fairly new to the concept of generic types.

---

Given that I am specifically needing my class to be a `MonoBehaviour`; can I make a custom generic class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, such as in my example?

```
public class SplineWalker<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : IBezierInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Theraot said: No, Unity does not support that.

But an alternative would be to use composition instead of inheritance. Instead of having a `SplineWalker` *for* `IBezierInterface`, create a `SplineWalker` *with* an `IBezierInterface`.

```
public class SplineWalker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IBezierInterface spline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you present is valid C#, yet as far as I know it is not supported by Unity (giving a "Generic MonoBehaviours are not supported" <strike>error</strike> warning on the console when trying to use `AddComponent` for it).

If you need to have multiple implementations of this class with different generic parameters, you may subclass again to make non-generic classes. You may also consider using a template solution (such as T4) to generate the code files.

Comment: I now realise the logical implications of a "generic MonoBehaviour" . Oddly, I am not getting any errors. That is a very good alternate, though. If no one offers a better resolution within a day, I will accept this answer.